# How can I know when dialog is shown

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm making electron app with vue + Vuetify.
with dialog, can make modal, but want to modify some div in dialog after it has shown.

using `$refs`, can't find before dialog opened.
I want to trigger some event when dialog opened like a binding event `show.bs.modal` as bootstrap.
is there any way to trigger when dialog has shown?

I can use with Updated with `$nextTick` but it is not a good solution can also be triggered other values has updated.

```
<v-dialog ref="alarmModal"> <-- okay
  <v-card-text ref="alarmModalPrices" style="height:300px"> <-- undefinded in methods or mounted
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>

<script>
export default {
mounted(){
  this.$refs.alarmModal.show = function () {  //<-- okay

   }
  this.$refs.alarmModalPrices.show = function () {  //<-- error

   }
},
updated () {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
      this.$refs.tempAlarmPrices.scrollTop = 50 // <-- okay, but also triggered when other values updated
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also use Eventbus to make event fire.
Still don't understand to make event fire and access its DOM

```
<v-dialog ref="alarmModal" easer>
  <v-card-text ref="alarmModalPrices" style="height:300px">
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>
<script>
import { EventBus } from '../plugins/event-bus'
export default {
mounted(){
  this.$refs.alarmModal.show = function () {
    EventBus.$emit('fire') // <-- work
  }
}
updated(){
  this.$nextTick(function () {
      this.$refs.tempAlarmPrices.scrollTop = 300 // <-- work
      console.log(this.$refs.tempAlarmPrices.scrollTop) // return 300
      var root = this
      EventBus.$on('fire', function () { // <-- called when event fired
        root.$refs.tempAlarmPrices.scrollTop = 500 // <-- not work
        console.log(root.$refs.tempAlarmPrices.scrollTop) // return 0
      })
    })
}
}
</script>
```